# Creating JSX in a stateless component through a function

Tags: javascript, reactjs, web-applications, ecmascript-6, functional-programming

Please refer to the code below. Is there a way to achieve what I'm trying to do?

I'm trying to create conditional JSX based on Props value, but within a seperate function.

not sure how to get it to work.

```js
import React from 'react';

function Greetings(props) {
  console.log(props);

  function showGreeting() {
    switch(props.message) {
      case '2':
        return "Howdy! Everything seems shiny.";
      case '3':
        return "Well well, who do we have here :)";
      case '4':
        return "Welcome back. We missed you!";
      case 'default':
        return "Hello there, Good Morning!";
    }
  }

  return (
    <div>
      {this.showGreeting}
    </div>
  )
}

export default Greetings;
```

The end result is an error:

> `TypeError: Cannot read property 'showGreeting' of undefined`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're trying to call `this.showGreeting` but `this` here is just a function not react component.

You have to use `<div>{showGreeting()}</div>` (attention to `()` which calls a function) because this function is defined not on function, but during function definition

Comment: To make it simple, @Vignesh Sharma your main return clause must be `<div>{showGreeting()}</div>`

Comment: Yes, including this in this.showGreeting was stupid of me. 
But I did not realize it should be a function call like so { showGreeting() }

Comment: Thanks for the quick response @asiniy :)